# Cannot configure Pig to store intermediate file into LZO format

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am learning Pig, I want to store the intermediate result in LZO format.

I have successfully downloaded, compiled and installed the `lzo codecs`.

When I try to run a `PigLatin` script with this command:

```
pig
-Djava.library.path=<path to the lzo library> 
-Dpig.tmpfilecompression=true 
-Dpig.tmpfilecompression.codec=lzo org.apache.pig.Main  myscript.pig
```

it fails, reporting this error:

```
 ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. LZO codec class not specified. Did you forget to set property io.compression.codec.lzo.class?
```

I have also tried to play with `core-site.xml` and `mapred-site.xml` but I was not able to solve the problem.

Can anyone help me fixing it?

Comment: -Djava.library.path=<path to the lzo library>  Did you literally put the line as   shown ??

Answer (score 0):

**-Djava.library.path= path to the lzo library**

Did you literally put the line as   shown ?? If yes please give it the path of lzo library. If you are OK with other compression simply change the output file name with .zip extension and run the same pig script without overriding any compression properties provided you are using  0.9 or greater version o pig.